# Recaptcha api gives internal server error

Tags: recaptcha

Using recaptcha in one of my JEE based application.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=KEY_VALUE_HERE"></script>
```

I can see the captcha when the application is deployed on local machine and it looks fine:

[image]

but getting an error when I deploy the application on development server, all I see is:

[image]

I view the source and can see the urls are same and when I hit it via browser I can see the same error in the browser as well.

[image]

Comment: Also it looks like you're using ReCaptcha v1, which will be deprecated in March, so you should probably be using v2 for a new project anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate of the other one (two different error messages).  That said, if the original poster could add a lot more detail it would help to resolve the issue.